# Unable to map a list of numbers in API-Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

How do I create a mapping for a list of numbers object in API gateway? I am trying to post a list of integers using **POST** request.  I tried working with **NS** attribute but got the Error.

**Error:**

```
{
  "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"
}
```

However, it works well when I have **N** attribute and post a single integer value.

[image: JSON input]

[image: Mapping template]

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to map your request payload to DynamoDB JSON String. You can apply a velocity template like this one,

```
{
    "TableName":"ABC",
    "Item": {
        "id": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
        },
        "name": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.name')"
        },
        "price": {
            "L": [
                #set($prices=$input.path('$.price'))
                #foreach($p in $prices)
                {
                    "N": "$p"
                }#if ($velocityCount < $prices.size()), #end
                #end
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Method Request Body:

```
{
    "name":"Test",
    "price": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Endpoint Request Body:

```
    {
    "TableName": "ABC",
    "Item": {
        "id": {
            "S": "test-invoke-request"
        },
        "name": {
            "S": "Test"
        },
        "price": {
            "L": [
                {
                    "N": "1"
                },
                {
                    "N": "2"
                },
                {
                    "N": "3"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```